# OnCollisionExit is not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is `OnCollisionExit` not being called? I am using both `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` but unfortunately only `OnCollisionEnter` is being called.

```
public bool HandleCollided = false;

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "RightHandAnchor")
    {
        HandleCollided = true;
    }
}

public void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "RightHandAnchor")
    {
        HandleCollided = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to copy the code that calls your functions if you want that we can help

Comment: The functions are called by default since i have added box collider to the object and this script to the same object.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Ho, I had not seen the unity flag.

Comment: Do you change something in the RigidBody or anything else in your Scene (e.g. disabling Colliders, objects) after `OnCollisionEnter`?

Comment: No i do not change or disable anything from the scene or through script.

Comment: There are two objects that collides with each other. One has sphere collider attached to it and another has box collider. One of the objects have rigidbody attached as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to tell why your code isn't working based the given snippet - this code depends on the configuration of each of the `GameObjects'` inspector windows in the editor.

Both the `GameObject` that this script is attached to and the colliding `GameObject` must have one `Collider` component attached to each of them (for example, a `BoxCollider` component or a `SphereCollider` component). Both `Colliders` must have their `isTrigger` checkboxes disabled. The `GameObject` that this script is attached to must also have a `Rigidbody` component attached.

In order to debug this situation, add `Debug.Log()` statements in your functions. This is generally good practice, and it might be that the function is being called but the conditional statement is not true.

Here are some additional ideas on what might be going wrong:

- You may be changing the name of the colliding `GameObject` somewhere else in your code.
- You may be destroying the `GameObject`.
- It might be that neither function was being called and `HandleCollided` was being changed elsewhere in your code.
- It might be that the parameter, `col`, is not what you expect.

```cs
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision Enter!");
    Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name);
}
public void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    Debug.Log("Collision Exit!");
    Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have tried to do everything still its the same result. 
(a) I have two gameObjects. The first one has a rigid body attached to it with gravity and kinematic components disabled. It has a sphere collider component attached with isTrigger disabled. 
(b) The second gameObject has a box collider attached to it with isTrigger disabled.
(c) The above script is attached to the second gameObject.

I am getting the message "Collision Enter!" but not for "Collision Exit!"

Comment: That's strange, thanks for trying the script out. There might be a physics setting somewhere in Unity that I'm unaware of, but you'd know if you changed anything in your project settings. If you're still having problems, try setting up and running the same script in a new scene, or new project, and if you're still having issues I'd try a fresh install of Unity. It's really unlikely that anything is wrong with your installation and causing this, but at least setting up the objects again would guarantee that that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you said "There are two objects that collides with each other. One has sphere collider attached to it and another has box collider. One of the objects have rigidbody attached as well." On which one is the code? and yes this matters! only 1 of the objects will keep track of the exit meaning that if it's the non-kinematic it will not work.

Comment: The second gameObject with only box collider attached has the code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately using OnCollisionExit did not work so instead I used OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit. I activated "isTrigger" for both objects.

```
  public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    Debug.Log("entered");
    if (col.gameObject.name == "RightHandAnchor")
    {
        HandleCollided = true;
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("exit");
    if (other.gameObject.name == "RightHandAnchor")
    {

        print("No longer in contact with " + other.transform.name);
        HandleCollided = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-kinematic rigidbody attached to your object to get the event for OnCollisionExit

Comment: This does not really answer the question since without it also `OnCollisionEnter` would not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OnCollisionEnter()` and `OnTriggerExit()` !!

Example:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
      if((collision.gameObject.GetComponent<AttributeManager>().attributes & doorType) != 0)
        {
            this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;
        }
    }


private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = false;
}
```